# CPRecordLoadHandler Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am mystified by a memory leak: It says the responsible library is "AppSupport" and the Responsible Frame is "CPRecordLoadHandler".  Not quite sure where to begin.  I know that it's when a specific view controller loads so obviously I can narrow it down a bit but I can't find a single result in Google that explains what a CPRecordLoadHandler memory leak comes from.

Comment: paste in the code for the ViewDidLoad method, hopefully then we will be able to see what is going on.